# How to Update Cascade Select Field in C#

Tags: c#, jira

I'm trying to update a custom cascade select field in C# (using Atlassian Jira library) but to no avail. Below is the code snippet I have:

```
var issue = jira.Issues.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "123");
var ca = issue.CustomFields.First(x => x.Name == "My Cascade Field");
ca.Values[1] = "new child"; // [0] is parent value, [1] is child value
issue.SaveChanges();
```

Though SaveChanges got executed successfully the changes were not saved. The child value ("new child") is indeed a valid value for the parent.

What do I need to update a cascade select field?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Posting code here to help if someone runs into the same problem:

```
var issue = jira.Issues.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "123");
var ca = issue.CustomFields.First(x => x.Name == "My Cascade Field");
string[] n = { "Existing Parent Value", "New Child Value" };
ca.Values = n;

issue.SaveChanges();
```